# Objective C, line up and colorize labels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm am trying to line up and colorize tags in my application in the same line. Yet I don't know how I'd go about doing this. Let's say I have an array of tags, all with different colors.

```
NSArray *MyArray = @[
                     @"#BlackSabbath", // red
                     @"#Dio", // blue
                     @"#TenaciousD" // yellow
                     ];
```

And I wanted to display them in a line. Well I know I could just create a single UILabel and stick them all in there as an NSString. However then how would I go about colorizing them? If this were HTML I could use span tags, but I don't believe there's an equivalent in Objective C.

I know I could also just line up a bunch of `UILabel`s and colorize them individually, but I don't know how to adjust the width depending on the size text, since the text length of some tags will be longer than others.

Comment: As long as the label is wide enough to fit the widest text, that width will work for all of them no matter how narrow they are...

Comment: Yes, but then how would I line them up properly? If I go with the longest text then I'll have ridiculously spacing between #Dio and #TenaciousD in the example I gave.

Comment: NSAttributedString to use different colors in only one UILabel.

Comment: oooooooh. Perfect, I'll look into it and post a code example if/when I figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Ian, you're putting them all on the same line?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make that clear but I guess "single line" isn't as clear as "same line". Editing for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that, this is from some code of mine, you should change it a little, but I think you can figure out the big picture. I use it to print names with background color separated by commas(with no background), such as facebook tagging in a UILabel:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * hashtagAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
    [hashtagAttributedString beginEditing];
    NSAttributedString * comma = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@","];
    //Iterate trough array of users
    for (AFUser * user in self.selectedUsers) { 
        NSAttributedString *myString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString: user.userSurnameAndName attributes:
                                        @{ NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.525490 green:0.803922 blue:0.301961 alpha:1.000000] ,
                                           NSFontAttributeName : self.taggedUsersLabel.font
                                           }];

        [hashtagAttributedString appendAttributedString:myString];
        if (self.selectedUsers.count > 1) {
            [hashtagAttributedString appendAttributedString:comma];
        }
    }
    [hashtagAttributedString endEditing];
    self.taggedUsersLabel.attributedText = hashtagAttributedString;
```

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me a good hour of figuring out how to implement this myself.

Answer (score 1):

## Suggestion

If you have ever used HTML, you can use this library to customize labels:

- [MarkupLabel](https://github.com/schwa/MarkupLabel)

## Example Code

A simple method

```
NSString *theMarkup = @"<b>Hello world</b>";
[theLabel setMarkup:theMarkup];
```

Creating a custom style

```
// Here's the markup we want to put into our UILabel. Note the custom <username> tag
NSString *theMarkup = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<username>%@</username> %@", theUsername, theBody];

NSError *theError = NULL;

// Create a transformer and set up the standard styling (that part is optional)
CMarkupTransformer *theTransformer = [[CMarkupTransformer alloc] init];
[theTransformer addStandardStyles];

// Create custom attributes for our new "username" tag
NSDictionary *theFormatDictionary = @{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
    kMarkupFontNameMetaAttributeName: @"Helvetica",
    };
[self addFormatDictionary:theFormatDictionary forTag:@"username"];

// Transform the markup into a NSAttributedString
NSAttributedString *theAttributedString = [theTransformer transformMarkup:inMarkup baseFont:self.font error:&theError];

// Give the attributed string to the CCoreTextLabel.
self.label.attributedString = theAttributedString;
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually come from a web dev background. However I'm trying to do everything with as much vanilla objective c as possible for learning purposes.

Comment: I have used this library, and it helps me a lot, even that I am not good on Web Development. Here some basic HTML tags are required which are very easy to use.